# The Euclidean norm ||r|| of a rotation

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Please let me know what is the Euclidean norm of a rotation vector;
and the difference from Euler angles.

I met these terms in the following text ; although your answers do not need to respect the writer's intention at all , because you do not know whether the writer uses the terms correctly or not.

Thank you very much.

---

Rotation Vector
The first three 16bit data values are a directed rotation vector presentation of the
rotation velocity and are NOT three Euler angles as might be assumed from the
previous section “How Data should be used”. The Euclidean norm ||r|| of the rotation
vector r = (data[0], data[1], data[2]) is the rotation velocity about the vector r.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is about *attitude parameterisation* - a rotation vector is one method of describing an attitude; Euler angles are another.

The ultimate description of a rotation is generally considered to be a 3x3 *rotation matrix* (in 3-space). However, since there are only 3 degrees of freedom in a rotation matrix, then there is considerable redundancy in its representation. Additionally, a rotation matrix does not really provide an intuitive description of what the rotation looks like.

So, what are some ways we can represent the rotation matrix? We can:

- Perform 3 successive rotations, each around a defined axis (Euler Angles); or
- Perform a single rotation about a fixed axis (Rotation vector)

Hence for Euler angles, we can create our rotation matrix as:
$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_x(\phi)   \mathbf{R}_y(\theta) \mathbf{R}_z(\psi)$, which consists [three successive rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles); a rotation about Z by angle $\psi$, followed by a rotation about the (new) y-axis by $\theta$ followed by rotation about the new x-axis by $\phi$. Classically, these are *roll* ($\phi$), *pitch* ($\theta$) and *yaw* ($\psi$) in the aerospace world.

A rotation vector $\mathbf{\rho}$ consists of a rotation about axis $\frac{\mathbf{\rho}}{\parallel\mathbf{\rho}\parallel}$ by angle  $\parallel\mathbf{\rho}\parallel$, except where $\parallel\mathbf{\rho}\parallel = 0$, in which the rotation matrix is simply the identiy matrix. To recover the rotation matrix, the matrix exponential is used:
$\mathbf{R} = \operatorname{exp}(\left[\mathbf{\rho}\right]_\times)$ where $\left[\mathbf{\rho}\right]_\times$ is a skew symmetric matrix constructed as $\left[\mathbf{\rho}\right]_\times = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\rho_{z} & \rho_{y} \\ \rho_{z} & 0 & -\rho_{x} \\ -\rho_{y}  & \rho_{x} & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Fortunately, there is a shortcut to calculating the matrix exponential called the [Rodrigues Rotation Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html).

In short: Euler angles are not the same as a rotation vector (except for very small angles, but that's another story).  They cannot be used interchangeably.

There are many many more representations of attitude. [Unit Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions) are common. If you need a cure for insomnia, take a read of [this survey paper on attitude representations](http://www.malcolmdshuster.com/Pub_1993h_J_Repsurv_scan.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The euclidean norm for a 3-dimensional vector is defined as:

$\|\mathbf{r}\|=\sqrt{r_x^2+r_y^2+r_z^2}$

No matter what the interpretation of this vector is. In this case it seems the author uses a compact version of the axis-angle representation, where the vector $\mathbf{r}$ is the axis of rotation and the angle (or in this case angular velocity) is decoded in the norm of the vector (as for the rotation axis a direction/unit vector suffices).

So the rotation is a rotation about the axis $\mathbf{u}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{\|\mathbf{r}\|}$ with the angle/velocity $\theta=\|\mathbf{r}\|$.

Euler angles on the other hand are three consecutive angles representing three consecutive rotations about coordinate axes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation would be that something is spinning about the central axis defined by $\langle \textrm{data}[0],\textrm{data}[1],\textrm{data}[2]\rangle$, and that it is rotating at an angular velocity of $v$ radians per unit of time (in the counterclockwise direction), where $$v=\|r\|=\sqrt{\textrm{data}[0]^2+\textrm{data}[1]^2+\textrm{data}[2]^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.